# Swift UITableView : Datasource assigning Issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, swift-playground

This is a simple `UITableView` code that is **working correctly** in playground:

```
import UIKit

class MyDataSuorce : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Value2, reuseIdentifier: nil)

        cell.textLabel.text = "Row #\(indexPath.row)"

        return cell;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 4
    }

}


let list = UITableView(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,300), style: .Plain)
let d = MyDataSuorce()
list.dataSource = d
list.reloadData()
```

But when I first tried this code, **it doesn't work and just show an empty `UITableView`:**

```
let list = UITableView(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,300), style: .Plain)
list.dataSource = MyDataSuorce()
list.reloadData()
```

**What's wrong with second code ?**

**EDIT:**

This is the console Output for `list.dataSource = MyDataSuorce()` :

> Playground execution failed: error: error: Couldn't lookup symbols: _memmove

Comment: What is the content of the MyDataSource() method?

Comment: @akashg There's no other code. What you see is all of my code.

Comment: Try `list.dataSource = self`

Comment: @akashg `self` is obviously undefined in global scope !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I resolve the "**Why?**"...

I think, it's about swift variable **lifetime**. (correct?)

In second code, I just forgot that returned object (by `MyDataSource()`) will be exist during that line of code.